# Error during update and installation of new packages

Tags: package-management

This error occur both in Synaptic and via terminal so I can't update or install new packages:

```
LANG=en_US;sudo dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gens:i386:
 gens:i386 depends on libc6.
 gens:i386 depends on libgcc1.
 gens:i386 depends on libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.4.0).
 gens:i386 depends on libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.4.0).
 gens:i386 depends on libpng12-0.
 gens:i386 depends on libsdl1.2debian (>= 1.1.3).
 gens:i386 depends on libstdc++6.
 gens:i386 depends on xdg-utils.
 gens:i386 depends on zlib1g.
dpkg: error processing gens:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 gens:i386
```

I searched the package to remove it but I didn't found it. And when I try to install something from synaptic show me this:

```
Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_assistant_set_page_header_image: assertion `child != NULL' failed at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Gnome.pm line 27, <> line 4.
dpkg: errore fatale non recuperabile, uscita: [fatal error not recoverable, exit]
 errore di sintassi: gruppo "cdemu" sconosciuto nel file statoverride [syntax error: "cdemu" group unknown in the file staoverride(?)]
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

**Output of dpkg -l gens**

```
raffaele@Natty:~$ LANG=en_US;dpkg -l gens*
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version        Description
+++-==============-==============-============================================
un  gens           <none>         (no description available)
```

**Output of dpkg -l *cdemu**

```
raffaele@Natty:~$ dpkg -l *cdemu*
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Nome           Versione       Descrizione
+++-==============-==============-============================================
ii  cdemu-client   1.4.0-0ubuntu1 Command-line client to control CDEmu daemon
ii  cdemu-daemon   1.4.0-0ubuntu1 CDEmu daemon
un  cdemu-daemon-d <none>         (nessuna descrizione disponibile)
ii  gcdemu         1.4.0-0ubuntu1 GNOME application to control CDEmu daemon
```

**Output of cat /var/lib/dpkg/statoverride**

```
raffaele@Natty:~$ cat /var/lib/dpkg/statoverride
root mlocate 2755 /usr/bin/mlocate
mpd audio 755 /var/lib/mpd
mpd audio 755 /var/lib/mpd/playlists
mpd audio 755 /var/log/mpd
mpd audio 755 /var/run/mpd
hplip root 755 /var/run/hplip
root ssl-cert 710 /etc/ssl/private
root cdemu 2755 /usr/bin/cdemud
mpd audio 640 /etc/mpd.conf
root crontab 2755 /usr/bin/crontab
```

Comment: Show the output of `dpkg -l gens*`

Comment: How did you install the `gens` package? Can you post a link to it? Can you also post `dpkg -l *cdemu*` and `cat /var/lib/dpkg/statoverride`?

Comment: I've installed it some time ago - but I've never had problems with it - via an i386 deb forced package (for an amd64). I don't remember where I found it. (And I haven't the .deb anymore).

Answer (score 3):

I've found and removed the .deb with

```
LANG=en,us sudo dpkg -r gens:i386
```

Now I've to resolve the other cdemu/gnome issue (look above).

**Finally I found a solution (I hope will help someone):**

In a terminal, type

```
sudo gedit /var/lib/dpkg/statoverride
```

delete the row about cdemu in the file

```
root cdemu 2755 /usr/bin/cdemud
```

Save it. Now you can update. (The problem was an [ubuntu natty bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/debconf/+bug/721738))